# Javascript can't read null

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript integration to submit a form that will call the factorial function in my javascript. I use the scripts and style plugin to integrate the javascript code. But it ends with an error at `var n` in the script.

```
Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLInputElement.factorial
```

Below is the code.
In my post I put:

```
<form id="cal_factorial">  
Enter No:<input type="number" id="num" name="number"/><br/>  
<input type="button" value="factorial" id="factorialize"/>  
</form>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

In the head I have the script as:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
document.querySelector("#factorialize").onclick = factorial;
});

function factorial(){

var n=document.getElementById("#num").value;
var ans =1;
    if(n>1){
        var trail = n*(n-1)
        ans = ans *trail;
        n-=1;
    }

document.querySelector("#answer").innerHTML = ans;
}
```

Anything wrong with the definition?

Comment: `getElementById` doesnt require a CSS style selector (including the #), just pass the ID of the element as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("#num").value;
```

is incorrect.

it should be

```
document.getElementById("num").value;
```

without the #

Answer (score 0):

Remove the hashtag in getElementById,

```
var n=document.getElementById("num").value;
```

Answer (score -1):

There might be something wrong with scope, the code look ok

have a look here

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onsubmit